# JCalendar sets to March 30 when February is chosen

Tags: calendar, monthcalendar, jcalendar, propertychangelistener, dayofmonth

Code consists of just month and year can be chosen in [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar), by default the day is 30 and 28 for February, the issue comes when I choose February, automatically [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar) sets to March 30; this is the code; it is in `PropertyChange` event of [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar).

```
Calendar cal = PFI.getCalendar();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if(month==1){
    cal.set(year, 1 , 28);
    PFI.setCalendar(cal);
}
else
{
    cal.set(year, month , 30);
    PFI.setCalendar(cal);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Best if you can find a calendar UI component that supports java.time, they exist. Otherwise convert.

Comment: In either calendar, use named constants. Why not use `JMonthChooser` and `JYearChooser` side-by-side, maybe with a common listener?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the suggestions of [@Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72038635/jcalendar-sets-to-march-30-when-february-is-chosen#comment127387542_72038635) and [@Catalina Island](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72038635/jcalendar-sets-to-march-30-when-february-is-chosen#comment127692469_72038635), the fragment below illustrates `JYearChooser` and  `JMonthChooser` in a `GridLayout`. A common listener then uses [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to display the last day of the selected year and month.

[image: year month image]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
JMonthChooser jmc = new JMonthChooser();
JYearChooser jyc = new JYearChooser();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Last day of month:");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField last = new JTextField(8);
label.setLabelFor(last);
PropertyChangeListener myListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(jyc.getYear(), jmc.getMonth() + 1, 1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        last.setText(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    }
};
myListener.propertyChange(null);
jmc.addPropertyChangeListener("month", myListener);
jyc.addPropertyChangeListener("year", myListener);
panel.add(jyc);
panel.add(jmc);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(last);
```